# Rename VM, IP and Disk names

Tags: google-cloud-platform, rename

I have two VMs, IPs and Disks that I created a while ago and I renamed the VM. The OCD in me want to use the same naming syntax for the IPs and disks too.

Is there a workaround I can rename the IP without losing the current IP address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, there is no way to change the name of a static IP once reserved, and it is stated on the [restriction from this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address#before-you-begin:%7E:text=You%20cannot%20change%20the%20name%20of%20a%20static%20IP%20address.)

a workaround could be is to [add labels](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/labeling-resources#add_or_update_labels_to_existing_resources) to the IP

There is already a filed [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35904550) to add this option, however, there is no ETA for the said feature.